# How to check why a docker build slow?

Tags: docker

I'm building my go program via:

```
RUN go install .
```

If I run the same command `go install .` on my host machine (with all cache pruned) I can see my CPU working hard (> 50% all cores). The same command run via Docker in contrast seem not use that much CPU and result is really slow build time.

Is their any way I can check resource usages for `docker build` command, something like `docker stats`?

Comment: There are a bunch of --cpu-* and --memory-* flags on the docker build command. You could try allocating the build more resources.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I check them all, if I understand the docs correctly, those flags during build time will be inherit to the running container after that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a sufficiently new Docker available, try using [Docker BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/):

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build ...
```

I experienced a significant increase in build speed after switching to BuildKit.